Why is PIC not detecting voltage on VDD pin?
I am using MPLAB IDE and am trying to load a square wave onto a pin of the PIC. I got the following error message:
The configuration is set for the target board to supply its own power but no voltage has been detected on VDD. Please ensure you have your target powered up and try again. Connection failed.
I am using PICKIT 5 and the pinout is as follows:

I connected the VDD of the PICkit5 to the VDD of the PIC microcontorller and got the message above. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Do you supply power to PIC VDD?

Is the board where the PIC installed powered up properly with the correct voltage?

the PIC is the target board ... the message tells you how the power connection is configured

I figured it out. I was trying to power the board through MPLAB IDE but had to go into MPLAB IPE.

You’ve configured the target to provide power. The board with the PIC on it must be powered from its own power source. Pickit checks for presence of this supply to the VDF pin of the PIC chip. In your case it is missing, ie. the PIC has no power to it.
Fix is simple: power up the target board (the one with the PIC on it).
